# I have no other

Tags: sentence-construction

If someone asks me 'Do you have another book?' can I reply 'I have no other book.'

My question is that should the noun after no other be plural or singular in the given context?

Answer (score 1):

Both "I have no other book" and "I have no other books" are correct.  I suspect that the average US-English native speaker would be more likely to say "books".

Answer (score 0):

"I have no other book" and "I have no other books" are both correct.  The plural form sounds more natural, unless you've been asked a question that presumes that you'll only have one ("What about your other book?" -- "But I have no other book!").

At http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv354.shtml we read:

> With countable nouns, no is normally followed by plural forms. It
>   sounds more natural and makes better sense to say:   *It was early
>   December and there were no leaves on the trees. No dogs, unless they
>   are on a lead, are allowed in the flower garden. No road accidents*
>   *were reported in Chelsea throughout August.*

("There was no leaf on the street" sounds very odd unless you were looking for a particular leaf or expecting to find only one.  "No road accident was reported" sounds OK, but "no road accidents" is more likely.)

> Sometimes, no may be followed by singular or plural nouns, depending on whether one is thinking of one or more than one:
>   *It was 9 a.m., yet there was no policeman on duty outside the embassy.* 
>   *It was 9 a.m., yet there were no policemen on duty outside the embassy.*

So, "Do you have another book?" could be answered "I have no other book" (perhaps suggesting that you think the presumption is that you would only have one book, or only one relevant to the discussion) or "I have no other books".

"I have no other book" (or "books") is slightly formal.  More likely responses in ordinary English might include:

- "I have no others"
- "I don't have another" (singular)
- "I don't have any others" (plural)
- "I don't"
- "I haven't"